# Groovy scripts in Kibana scripted field

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy, lucene, kibana

Is there a way that I can specify Groovy script file name in "script" textarea while creating a scripted field.

[image]

Lucene expressions work well on that field with limitations to numeric values, but how to specify the script file name and passing inputs to script file?

I have tried giving the script file name like below but it didn't work.

```
{"script":{"file":"MyScript"},"lang":"groovy"}
```

I have also noticed from [docs](https://www.elastic.co/blog/kibana-4-beta-3-now-more-filtery) that, latest elastic version defaults to Lucene expressions, but I suspect there should be a way to specify script type.

> UPDATE: As a security precaution, starting with version 4.0.0-RC1,
>   Kibana scripted fields default to Lucene Expressions, not Groovy, as
>   the scripting language.

Can someone let me know if it is possible and if possible, then the way of doing it?

Comment: It is currently not possible to choose the script language you want, but this might help: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/calling-groovy-script-from-kibana/2542/2

Answer (score 1):

The following instruction are for `elasticsearch` 2.x.

First you need to enable Groovy aggregations scripts in `elasticsearch.yml`:

```
script.engine.groovy.indexed.aggs: true
```

Then in your JSON Input of the relevant property in your visualization:
[image]

Lastly you need to put your script in the `config/scripts` folder

```
elasticsearch  
└── config  
    └── scripts  
        └── myscript.groovy
```

Don't forget to restart your `elasticsearch` after the above changes.

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work. Same error continues "Discover: Failed to parse expression: {"script":{"file":"MyScript"},"lang":"groovy"}"

Comment: @svjn I guess you are trying to add `{"script":{"file":"MyScript"},"lang":"groovy"}` directly in Kibana's "Settings->your-index->Scrtiped Fields". Instead (1) add the field but leave the `Script` empty there, (2) add the script in the `JSON Input` of your visualization. Anyhow, I've updated my answer.

Comment: +1 for '{"lang":"groovy"}' - that's also necessary if the scripted field was directly configured at the settings.